# Are Anonymous Types required when doing LINQ to SQL Projections?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I've been reading up on [Projections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693038.aspx) and while I find them fascinating, I also find they're not very transparant and Microsoft's documentation seems incomplete.

[This article](https://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2009/11/26/linq-to-sql-tricks-building-efficient-queries-that-include-reference-data-or-child-entities/) on it by Eugene Prystupa is quite excellent, but still leaves me with questions.

For example, is it required to use an Anonymous Type to do the shaping/projecting? Or could one also use custom named Types?

For example, would the following two code samples result in the same generated SQL?

```
var q = ctx.CustomerAddresses.Select(x => 
         new {
             CustomerAddress = ca,
             ca.Customer,
             ca.Address
         }).Take(3);
```

```
var w = ctx.CustomerAddresses.Select(x => 
         new CustomerAddressHelper() {
             CustomerAddress1 = ca,
             Customer1 = ca.Customer,
             Address1 = ca.Address
         }).Take(3);

public class CustomerAddressHelper
{
    public CustomerAddress CustomerAddress1;
    public Customer Customer1;
    public Address Address1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always prefer to use a strongly typed projection model, instead of dynamic - the generated SQL would be the same.

As far as SQL is concerned, all it needs to know is what columns it needs to return to satisfy the request. Whether you are populating a dynamic object, or a custom type object, is irrelevant from the SQL point of view.

A good/quick way to check what the SQL being executed actually is, is to run SQL Profiler, then watch what hits the DB when the results of the Linq-to-sql query are materialised